# Error while using ckeditor with Django version 2.x

Tags: django, django-models, ckeditor

Please be informed I researched Stack Overflow and ckeditor documentation and configured accordingly.

First I install ckeditor using

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

Then I configured my settings.py as below

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# media

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor"

# CKEditor settings
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
# This ensures you have all toolbar icons
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },

  }
```

Then I configured my urls.py (project's url) as below

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls'))
```

Then I ran command `collect static`
ckeditor statics are collected in right location defined in settings which is `/static/ckeditor/ckeditor`

After that I imported and used ckeditor richtextfield in my model

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.RichTextField()
```

While makemigrations i am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'RichTextField'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
post = models.RichTextField()
```

to:

```
post = RichTextField()
```

And in CKEDITOR_BASEPATH add "/" to the end.

```
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```